# Animate a list of images on a canvas

Tags: image, animation, racket

I am trying to show a list of images on a canvas using following code. However, an empty frame appears and no images appear till the entire 'for' loop is run and then the final effect is displayed in the frame.

```
#lang racket/gui
(require 2htdp/image)

(define frame (new frame%
                   [label "Example"]
                   [width  500]
                   [height 500]))

(send frame show #t) 
; (sleep 1)    ; tried this to allow time for frame to show properly; does not help; 

(new canvas% [parent frame]
     [paint-callback
      (lambda (canvas dc)
        (for ((i imglist))      ; imglist is a list of images to be displayed @ 1/second.
          (send dc clear)
          (send dc draw-bitmap 
                     (image->bitmap i) 
                     20 20)
          ; (send dc flush)     ; this statement also does not help;
          (sleep 1)             ; to show animation effect from list of images;
          ))])
```

The image->bitmap function is from: ;from: https://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2014-December/065110.html

```
(define (image->bitmap image)   
  (let* ([width (image-width image)]
         [height (image-height image)]
         [bm (make-bitmap width height)]
         [dc (send bm make-dc)])
    (send dc clear)
    (send image draw dc 0 0 0 0 width height 0 0 #f)
    bm))
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `paint-callback` is meant to quickly update the canvas and then return.
When it returns the system knows that the canvas is updated.

One way to do what you want: 1) Introduce a parameter that holds the image currently being displayed. 2) Make the `paint-callback` draw the current image. 3) Make a separate thread that changes the current image each second.

Note: Below I added +1 to the width and height in `image->bitmap`. The edges of the circle was cut-off.

```
#lang racket/gui
(require 2htdp/image)

(define images (list (circle 30 "outline" "red")
                     (circle 20 "outline" "red")
                     (circle 10 "outline" "red")
                     (circle  5 "outline" "red")))

(define current-image (make-parameter (first images)))

(define (image->bitmap image)   
  (let* ([width  (+ (image-width  image) 1)]
         [height (+ (image-height image) 1)]
         [bm     (make-bitmap width height)]
         [dc     (send bm make-dc)])
    (send dc clear)
    (send image draw dc 0 0 0 0 width height 0 0 #f)
    bm))

(define frame (new frame%
                   [label "Example"]
                   [width  500]
                   [height 500]))

(define canvas (new canvas% [parent frame]
                    [paint-callback
                     (lambda (canvas dc)
                       (send dc clear)
                       (send dc draw-bitmap (image->bitmap (current-image)) 20 20))]))

(send frame show #t) 

(thread (λ ()
          (let loop ([is images])
            (cond
              [(null? is) (loop images)]
              [else       (current-image (first is))
                          (send canvas on-paint)
                          (sleep 1)
                          (loop (rest is))]))))
```

Comment: Yes, it works very well. I found that I could also do "(send canvas get-dc)" to get dc object and then do draw-bitmap on it in an endless loop, but there the frame close button does not work and the process has to be STOPped from the DrRacket IDE. There is no such problem with your solution using thread.

Answer (score 0):

Following works:

```
(define images (list (circle 30 "outline" "red")
                     (circle 20 "outline" "red")
                     (circle 10 "outline" "red")
                     (circle  5 "outline" "red")))

(define (image->bitmap image)  
  (let* ([width (image-width image)]
         [height (image-height image)]
         [bm (make-bitmap width height)]
         [dc (send bm make-dc)])
    (send dc clear)
    (send image draw dc 0 0 0 0 width height 0 0 #f)
    bm))

(define frame (new frame% [label "Frame"] [width 300] [height 300]))
(define canvas (new canvas% [parent frame]))
(define dc (send canvas get-dc))

(send frame show #t)
(sleep/yield 1)

(let loop ()  
  (for ((i images))
    (send dc clear)
    (send dc draw-bitmap
          (image->bitmap i)
          20 20)
    (sleep 0.5))
  (loop))
```

However, the frame showing animation does not close but has to be stopped from IDE.